# Dynamically altering a BorderLayout in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, border-layout

I have a window with a BorderLayout, with a JPanel containing stuff put on CENTER, and a size of 800*250. I want that at the click of a button, that JPanel moves to NORTH and another JPanel gets to be on CENTER. I tried this, but it only resized my window without doing anything else.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,550));
            frame.removeAll();
            frame.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(southpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
            frame.pack();
        }
```

northpanel was before set on CENTER.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Can you try repainting the frame itself and not the content pane?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it, usually the add methods are overriden, so they add they add the components to the JFrame content pane, but the removeAll method isn't. So you have to invoke removeAll() on the content Pane

frame.getContentPane().removeAll();

Try this.

Comment: @lekroif You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add() and remove() methods are overriden so they do everything automatically on the content pane. Remember the JFrame is just a container, everything that matters is your content pane. The removeAll() method is not overriden like that. What you should do is:

```
frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
```

You can read more on the Oracle website :)

[Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)